# Adding Child Nodes on TreeView At Run-Time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this issue. I am trying to work with treeview at run-time. I am trying to add a child node and store into the database using EF.

The issue now is, how does the database place it as child node when retrieving it?

Take for instance, i have a root node called Users, and under that Users, there is a sub-node called "Names". if I place my mouse on a child node let’s say “Names” and maybe have a form to add a child node under “Names” and call it, “Godymn”. How does the database handles this and know how to place this as sub child node?. 
So far, when I try adding a child node inside “Names”, it adds it under Users. But I want it added under “Names” at run time. That’s where I am stuck.

So, far, here is my code….

```
  using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
            var q = (from i in db.test
                     select i);

            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Users");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);

            foreach (var item in q)
            {
                TreeNode nodes = new TreeNode(item.title);
                treeNode.Nodes.Add(nodes);
            }
        }
```

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: you should address part of your question: because it is misleading.  the question isn't how the database handles this (or even ADO.NET for that matter) - you don't even need a database configured to face the issue you're having.  IMO, You're simply asking how to work with Hierarchical Types with Entity Framework - which is a bit too broad a question really.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeNode` objects need to be added from bottom to top (at least to make sense in code); this not only speeds up the process, but also keeps code clean and readable. Create your top level nodes, then all of your child nodes. Finally, add your nodes in their respective places.

```
TreeNode users = new TreeNode("Users");
TreeNode names = new TreeNode("Names");
List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
foreach (var item in q)
    names.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item.Title));

users.Nodes.Add(names);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(users);
```

With respect to your question of how the database handles things, you should have a relational table for your child nodes with a column called `ParentNode` that is either `NULL`, `Empty` or contains the `Tag` associated with the parent node. This helps you build things the right way.